# SESSION hack in PHP

Tags: php, session

I was just wondering. Lets imagine i have a website with a login-system in PHP. And if the user succesfully logs in to the system the php sets something like: $_SESSION['user']="Loggedin".

And now, if you as a user of the website, could you just create your own PHP-script in your XAMPP folder or whatever and set the session user to loggedin and get access to my site?

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't know we gave our website users access to create and execute php scripts?

Comment: Some night time reading for you. [See here.](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: you can't create your own PHP script on a server u don't have access .

Comment: +1 for getting -5 with only 18 views.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry for this,
If you use Cookie for this then there's issue to be hacked and son on. But in Session, it will store on server side, so whether user can create a file and used or trying to get data from buy using session variable, they can't.

User can't get Session variable from the local server, they must have to access session variable from the same server.

And one more thing, this session is destroys when you close your browser.

Answer (score 1):

A PHP session stores user information on the server for later use.
So if you are making a session on your localhost, with the same name, that doesn't influence the one on the website/server.
Remember that session information is temporary and will be deleted after the user has left the website.